# Django - repeat ForeignKey vs. multi-level relationship

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Assuming below (simplified) database schema:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    ...

class Business(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
```

Is it better to include `site = models.ForeignKey(Site)` field in every site-related model (all above) and then ie.:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id=1)
invoice_site = invoice.site
```

or use multi-level relation like this:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id=1)
invoice_site = invoice.subscription.business.site
```

I have such situations in many places of my code and always wonder which option is better. First is cleaner, do not break "DRY" rules and prevents inconsistency but the other allows to gain performance and optimization improvements through preventing complicated database joins.

Of course I assume that site is always consistent in above models, so there is no possibility to have `Business` with site A and `Invoice` with site B.

Answer (score 1):

Well, relational database design has no place for `DRY`, it's all about relations. You need to think logically what the relationship structure of your application should be.

I couldn't speak definitively because I'm not in your shoes to understand the requirement 100%, but I'm almost certain that `site` shouldn't be directly associated with `Invoice`. `Invoice` is related to your business subscriptions and shouldn't depend on/know which site does the business happen. Same thing for `Subscription` model. A simple trouble if you have `site` in `Invoice` is that you are duplicating the relationship, and an `Invoice` couldn't exist if there's no such `site` yet.

I suggest you check out some basics of relational database design and gain a better understanding of the concept of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It would help you design a better schema without causing trouble with relations.